# PouchDB.sync -> GET https://myaccount.cloudant.com/?_nonce=123... 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to sync to Cloudant using Pouch 3.3.0 using the following code:

```
  var url = 'https://username:password@myaccount.cloudant.com/mydb';

        var sync = PouchDB.sync('mydb', url, {live: true})
          .on('change', function (info) {
            alert(info);
          }).on('denied', function (info) {
            alert(info);
          }).on('complete', function (info) {
            alert(info);
          }).on('error', function (err) {
            alert(err);
          });
```

However, I'm receiving the following error in the console log window:

```
GET https://myaccount.cloudant.com/?_nonce=1423729415820 403 (Forbidden)
```

I've seen some issues related to this (e.g. [#1646](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1646)) but I'm not clear what I need to do for working around the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure PouchDB catches the 403 and then keeps going. Are you sure replication isn't actually being stopped?

Comment: You could also try the #cloudant IRC room on freenode if you need support: irc://freenode.net/#cloudant

Comment: Ah, I seen a 404 in the console log first and then a note saying that was expected, but I didn't see a similar note for the 403 so presumed that the 403 wasn't handled.  It seems that the replication is starting, but no documents are getting replicated.

Comment: Try asking Cloudant for support. To me, your code looks like it should work. Are you sure your username and password are correct? They need to be URL-encoded if you are passing them in as part of the URL.

Comment: It all seems to be working ok.  The 403 was a red herring.